# Add a field to a Data Extension used as Journey entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a running email Journey that I want to add a new decision split to in order to send two different emails. I have a new field in SFDC that I will use to determine which email to send. My Journey runs off of a data extension entry source, to which I have added this field. However, in my new draft version of the Journey, I can't access this field in the logic for my decision split, even though it has been created in the DE and there is data. I can remove the current entry source, re-add it and then the field is accessible, but I have a lot of other decision splits so I don't want to risk introducing a bug and/or do the duplicative work to re-build these splits.

Is there a way I can access my new field for a decision split without rebuilding the entry source?

Comment: Are you getting a validation error when you copy over the existing journey to a new one (w/ the updated field) and revalidate? I find that I usually don't have to re-apply new configurations unless you're using the Salesforce Entry Event and your data model undergoes a large change (or you migrate to another org on SF side for some random reason like UAT > Prod).

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I deleted my current draft journey version, created a new version and the field appeared.